# how to write an update statement in sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table which has only two columns master_id and a group id column . And the data looks like the following

```
master_id   group_id
---------   --------
  M1          G1
  M2          G1
  M2          G2
  M3          G2
  M4          G3
```

.... and so on.

I need to write an update statement which selects all the master_ids that do not have group_id G1 (i.e. M2,M3 and M4) and if any one of them are part of the group G1 (M2 also has a G1 Group id) then update that group(M2 and M3 belongs to the same group) to have group id G1.
i.e. after update it should have

```
master_id   group_id
---------   --------
  M1          G1
  M2          G1
  M2          G1
  M3          G1
  M4          G3
```

How to do the same in sql ?

What I have tried so far is something like

```
Update dw_stuart_tbls.intrnl_cdc_id
FROM
(
  SELECT cnst_mstr_id
  FROM dw_stuart_tbls.intrnl_cdc_id
  WHERE group_id NOT LIKE '%G1%'
  AND cnst_mstr_id NOT IN 
  ( SELECT cnst_mstr_id
  FROM dw_stuart_tbls.intrnl_cdc_id
  WHERE group_id LIKE '%G1%'))upd_tbl
```

Please suggest a way .

Comment: which db system? mysql != sqlserver.

Comment: any . More appropriately Teradata

Comment: Looks like hierarchical query...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are merging G2 into G1?

Comment: The update is "UPDATE table SET column = something". I think you're missing a set command, and what you're updating looks like a column name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Teradata is, but you can accomplish what you want with a sub-select to get all the `master_id`s which have a `group_id` of `G2`.

```
UPDATE whatever
SET group_id = 'G1'
WHERE master_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT master_id
  FROM whatever
  WHERE group_id = 'G2'
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11cbe/2/0)

Comment: but if M2 is not also part of the group of M1(They share Group G1) ... then M2 's group id G2 need to be updated to G1 , right ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder Could you add that part to your example?